# Way to make this if statement with multiple conditions shorter?

Tags: c++, performance, if-statement

I'm looking for a way to make this if statement more efficient or at least shorter. I was thinking, either `i` or `j` has to be `(n - 1)` or both or both `(n - 2)`.

```
if ((i == (n - 1) && j == (n - 1)) ||
    (i == (n - 1) && j == (n - 2)) ||
    (i == (n - 2) && j == (n - 1)) ||
    (i == (n - 2) && j == (n - 2)))
{
  // Code
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you just want to check if `i` and `j` are both `n-1` or `n-2`:

```
if ((i == (n - 1) || i == (n - 2)) &&
    (j == (n - 1) || j == (n - 2))
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((i == (n - 1) || i == (n - 2)) && (j == (n - 1) || j == (n - 2))
{
  // Code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whereas the simpler and more readable is

```
(i == (n - 1) || i == (n - 2)) && (j == (n - 1) || j == (n - 2))
```

With some tricks, we may remove some branches (but loose readability)

```
(i == (n - 1) || i == (n - 2))
```

is equivalent to

```
(i - (n - 2) == (n - 1) - (n - 2) || i - (n - 2) == 0)
```

or

```
(i - (n - 2) == 0 || i - (n - 2) == 1)
```

which can be written as any of the following:

- `unsigned(i - (n - 2)) < 2`
- `((i - (n - 2)) & ~0x1) == 0`
- `((i - (n - 2)) | 0x1) == 0x1`

And finally, when doing the same with `j` (and some more refactoring):

- `unsigned(i - (n - 2)) < 2 && unsigned(j - (n - 2)) < 2`
- `(((i - (n - 2)) | (j - (n - 2))) & ~0x1) == 0`
- `((i - (n - 2)) | (j - (n - 2)) | 0x1) == 0x1`

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((i-n+1)|(j-n+1)|0x1 == 0x1) {
   // ...
}
```

For the boolean condition to be true, the bitwise `OR` of `i-(n-1)`, `j-(n-1)` and `0x1` should be `0x1`. Thus it is obvious that `(i-(n-1)) | (j-(n-1))` needs to be either `0x0` or `0x1`. As I assume `i` and `j` are `int`s, the are stored in 2-bit complement and thus `-1` is expressed as `0xffffffff`, `0` is `0x0` and `1` is `0x1` and so on. If `(i-(n-1)) | (j-(n-1))` is `0x1` or `0x0` both `i-(n-1)` and `j-(n-1)` needs to be `0x1` or `0x0`.

Comment: Nearly, if `i == n-2`, we have false (`(-1) == 0x1`), `+1` should be `+2`. And code is less readable and more error prone. A comment should be added to explain the test.

Comment: @Jarod42 `i = n-2` means `(i-n+1) = -1 = 0xffffffff` (assuming 32-bit signed integer in 2bit complement). `0xffffffff | x` is `0xffffffff` regardless of what `x` is, and thus it would not be `0x1`.

Comment: That is my point: `i == n - 2 && j == n - 2` is a correct answer for OP, but not with your answer. (your is `i == n` or `i == n - 1`)

Comment: @Jarod42 That is a bitwise operator not the boolean operator.